# Problems when angles change from 360 back to 0

Tags: angle

I'm trying to determine if an object is moving clockwise or counterclockwise relative to another

I do this by making two vectors.

1st from the center object to the player object
2nd from the center object to the player object PLUS its velocity vector

I then get the angles of these vectors and compare them. + difference is counterClockwise, - difference is clockwise.

The problem comes when one of the angles passes from the 360-0 or vise versa because then the comparison breaks;

i.e. 
360-350 is +10 counterclockwise
10 - 360 is -350 clockwise

Whats the best way to determine if one angle is larger than another avoiding this problem?